# Updating an array in a loop in Julia, avoiding global variables

Tags: while-loop, global-variables, julia, updates

According to the performance tips for Julia in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html, we should avoid `global`variables. How can I then updated arrays in `while` loops avoiding `global` variables? As an example, I reproduce a very simple case, but I have more complicated cases of `while` loops, where I must always update `global` variables at each iteration:

```
i = 1 
x = 10

while i <10
    global x = x+2
    global i = i + 1
end
```

And here is a more complicated example, based on a code of mine:

```
function consensus(p::Float64)        
    prop=[1 rand() rand() rand() rand(); rand() 1 rand() rand() rand(); rand() rand()  1 rand() rand(); rand() rand() rand() 1 rand(); rand() rand() rand() rand() 1]
    prop=Symmetric(prop)
    thresh=sort(unique(prop))
    g=map(i -> adjmat(proptotmemecl,thresh,i),1:length(thresh))
    global listeclust=map(i -> comp(g,i),1:length(thresh))
    global sizeclust=map(i -> nbcc(listeclust,i),1:length(thresh))
    global sizesdelete=sort(filter(x-> x<=1000^p,unique(reduce(vcat,sizeclust))))
    while length(sizesdelete)>0
        ind2=map(i -> ind(listeclust,sizesdelete,i),1:length(thresh))
        ind4=map(i-> closest(prop,i),ind2)
        map(i -> agglom(g,ind2,ind4,i),1:length(thresh))
        global listeclust=map(i -> comp(g,i),1:length(thresh))
        global sizeclust=map(i -> nbcc(listeclust,i),1:length(thresh))
        global sizesdelete=sort(filter(x-> x<= 1000^p,unique(reduce(vcat,sizeclust))))
    end
    listeclustuniq=unique(listeclust)
end
```

Here, I created a function with arrays defined inside, where the `while` loop updates 3 of the arrays. `adjmat`, `comp`, `nbcc`, `ind`, `closest` and `agglom` are functions created earlier in my code. What I would like to know here is how I can update the 3 arrays `listeclust`, `sizeclust` and `sizesdelete` avoiding the `global` definition, for speeding performance.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do here is put all of this in a function.

```
function f()
     i=1...rest of code...
end
f()
```

Will mean that nothing is on final scope.

Comment: Ok ;-) Here I understand the goal. As I am aiming speed performance in Julia, I'm trying to avoid global variables. I have a much more complicated code, which is too long to reproduce here, where the `while` loop is inside a function and as the loop needs to update `global` arrays that are defined inside the function, I wanted to find a way to code the updating process avoiding `global` variables. I'm trying to create an example based on my code.

Comment: Pass the arrays into the function

Comment: As arguments of the function?

Comment: So if the global variable is called x,  write `function f(x)...` and then call it with `f(x)`. This means the function can specialize in the type of x to generate efficient code.

Comment: But the arrays are modified at each iteration. Should I define  the function with ! so that they can be modified at each iteration ?

Comment: ! Is only a convention, but yes. You should name it that way to signal the intent to mutate the argument.

Comment: Ok, will try it ;-)